# EF Core 7 - Multiple navigations on the same table for a single Relationship Key?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

We are migrating from EF 5.0 to EF Core 7.0 but facing some challenges while data modeling.

In EF 5 we could model multiple navigation properties with single foreign key on same table.

Please review the sample model classes.

```
 public  class tblParent
 {
     public long ID { get; set; }
     public string? Name { get; set; }

     public virtual ObservableCollection<tblChild> Childrens { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<tblChild>();
     public virtual ObservableCollection<tblChild> PartChildren { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<tblChild>();
     public virtual ObservableCollection<tblChild> LabourChildren { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<tblChild>();

 }
 public class tblChild
 {
     public long ID { get; set; }
     public long ParentID { get; set; }
     public int Type { get; set; }

     [ForeignKey(nameof(ParentID))]
     public  virtual tblParent? Parent { get; set; }

 }
```

I get the following error:

> Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship

How can I resolve this issue without changing the db schema?
Kindly request

It should work based on my previous EF 5 code.

Answer (score 0):

its not supported in ef7, however you can use shadow properties for the foreign key in tblChild.

```
public class tblChild
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long ParentID { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    public virtual tblParent? Parent { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
        .WithMany(p => p.Childrens)
        .HasForeignKey("ParentID")
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.ID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
        .WithMany(p => p.PartChildren)
        .HasForeignKey("PartParentID")
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.ID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>()
        .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
        .WithMany(p => p.LabourChildren)
        .HasForeignKey("LabourParentID")
        .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.ID)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>().Property<long>("ParentID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>().Property<long>("PartParentID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>().Property<long>("LabourParentID");

    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>().HasQueryFilter(c => EF.Property<long>(c, "ParentID") == c.ParentID && c.Type == 0);
    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>().HasQueryFilter(c => EF.Property<long>(c, "PartParentID") == c.ParentID && c.Type == 1);
    modelBuilder.Entity<tblChild>().HasQueryFilter(c => EF.Property<long>(c, "LabourParentID") == c.ParentID && c.Type == 2);
}
```

the shadow properties ParentID, PartParentID, and LabourParentID are used to map the navigation properties, and query filters are used to filter tblChild based on the Type value.

Comment: Still having same error . 'Cannot create a relationship between 'TableParent.PartChildren' and 'TableChild.Parent' because a relationship already exists between 'TableParent.Children' and 'TableChild.Parent'. Navigations can only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'TableChild.Parent' first in 'OnModelCreating'.'

Comment: try to add     .HasQueryFilter(c => EF.Property<long>(c, "ParentID") == c.ParentID && c.Type == 0); to each accordingly

Comment: Do you have any working code? will u plz provide any reference ? i tried everything but its not working.